# float перенос по экрану

Tags: c++, dll

мне надо сделать функцию чтоб перенести с одного места на другое но появляется ошибкаE0304

menu.cpp:

```
Menu::Float("x", Menu::Settings::x, (float)0, (float)1);
```

MenuFunctions.h:

```
 namespace Menu {
namespace Drawing {
    void Text(const char* text, RGBAF rgbaf, VECTOR2 position, VECTOR2_2 size, bool center);
    void Rect(RGBA rgba, VECTOR2 position, VECTOR2_2 size);
    void Spriter(std::string Streamedtexture, std::string textureName, float x, float y, float width, float height, float rotation, int r, int g, int b, int a);
} 
namespace Settings {
    extern VECTOR2 x;
   }
```

MenuFunctions.cpp:

```
void Menu::Drawing::Text(const char * text, RGBAF rgbaf, VECTOR2 position, VECTOR2_2 size, bool center)
{
UI::SET_TEXT_CENTRE(center);
UI::SET_TEXT_COLOUR(rgbaf.r, rgbaf.g, rgbaf.b, rgbaf.a);
UI::SET_TEXT_FONT(rgbaf.f);
UI::SET_TEXT_SCALE(size.w, size.h);
UI::BEGIN_TEXT_COMMAND_DISPLAY_TEXT("STRING");
UI::ADD_TEXT_COMPONENT_SUBSTRING_PLAYER_NAME((char*)text);
UI::END_TEXT_COMMAND_DISPLAY_TEXT(position.x, position.y);
```

}

```
void Menu::Drawing::Spriter(std::string Streamedtexture, std::string textureName, float x, float y, float width, float height, float rotation, int r, int g, int b, int a)
{
if (!GRAPHICS::HAS_STREAMED_TEXTURE_DICT_LOADED((char*)Streamedtexture.c_str()))
{
    GRAPHICS::REQUEST_STREAMED_TEXTURE_DICT((char*)Streamedtexture.c_str(), false);
}
else
{
    GRAPHICS::DRAW_SPRITE((char*)Streamedtexture.c_str(), (char*)textureName.c_str(), x, y, width, height, rotation, r, g, b, a);
}
```

}

```
void Menu::Drawing::Rect(RGBA rgba, VECTOR2 position, VECTOR2_2 size)
{
GRAPHICS::DRAW_RECT(position.x, position.y, size.w, size.h, rgba.r, rgba.g, rgba.b, rgba.a);
```

}

```
VECTOR2 Menu::Settings::x{ 0 };
```

Comment: Вы забыли рассказать, какая UI-библиотека используется

Comment: наверно глупо но что такое UI-библиотека

Comment: Откуда вы берете все эти классы и методы?

Comment: я наверно очень глупый (новичёк) скажите как их дстать?

Comment: Хорошо, как называется программа, в которой вы пишите код?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2017

Comment: А тип проекта?.

Comment: мда я очень глупый как его узнать

Comment: это?: Debug 64x

Comment: Когда вы содавали проект, вы наверняка выбирали его тип, там был виззард.

Comment: я сосдавал проект Visual C++ пустой проект, .NET Framework 4.6.2,
сортировка по умолчанию,
решение создать новое .
больше ничего нет

Comment: Если под .NET Framework, то это C++/CLI, а не C++.